# How to query documents in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When i try to find a document like 
const p1 = Profile.find()
console.log(p1) i should get all document in that collections but i'm getting different crap.
this is my simple schema in mongodb nodejs

```
    const ProfileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    subjects: [String],
    late: Boolean
});

const Profile = mongoose.model('profile',ProfileSchema);

const profile1 = Profile.find()
console.log(profile1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this -

```
Profile.find({}, function(err, profiles) {
   console.log(profiles);
});
```

Refer this for more details - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Answer (score 0):

`const profile1 = await Profile.find({});`

Since Mongoose supports async/await I would make the wrapping function `async` and call your find function using the await syntax.

Also make a point to pass in an empty object `{}` to your find function when you want to return all the documents in the collection.

More information here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find